# Evaluate a condition for an IF statment in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

I need to be able to generate a conditional condition in the IF statement.
The code should look something like this:

```
if($filter_by $operator $value) {
  # do something
}
```

Which can be for example: column1 > 10
That obviously doesn't work.
I tried doing this:

```
if(eval "$filter_by $operator $value")
```

but it also doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Someone asked a similar question around a month ago...

Comment: What kind of expression you want to evaluate?? Can you show your code where you are using it??

Answer (score 3):

The `eval` function takes a string, evaluates the string *in the current context* as Perl code and returns the result.

Interpolating the values directly is not going to work:

```
$arg1 = "ab cd";
$arg2 = "123";
$op = "==";

$result = eval "$arg1 $op $arg2";
```

would pass the string `ab cd == 123` to `eval`, which is *not* valid Perl code.

However, there is an easy solution as the `eval`'d code can see outside variables:

```
$result = eval('$arg1 ' . $op . ' $arg2');
```

The argument names don't get interpolated, and you can construct arbitrary code.

Note that this might be a BadIdea(TM), as you could introduce malicious code in the operator: `$op = '; system "rm -rf /"; '`

Comment: Have you tested the last bit? :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what expression you are using that don't work.. The code as I show below works fine for me..

```
#!/perl/bin
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my $column = 12;
if ($column > 10) {
    say "Greater";

} else {
    say "Not greater";
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the operator to be dynamic. He wants to have `>` in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way is to use subroutine references:

```
my $compare = sub { return $_[0] > $_[1] };
if ($compare->(1,2)) { print "One is greater than two"}

$compare = sub { return $_[0] < $_[1] };
if ($compare->(1,2)) { print "One is less than two"}
```

This is considered better style than `eval()`, both because of the security issues that amon mentions and for clearer code.

That being said, `eval()` is perfectly fine in many situations.